# Convert a simple .md file to a gitlab page

Tags: html, continuous-integration, gitlab, markdown

There are several options for setting up Gitlab pages. Most of them have a lot of awesome tools. But it is not really necessary for us. That's why we wondered if it was possible to convert a `.MD` (readme.md) file to a single Gitlab page. So we can write in `.MD` markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written a script which converts the md file to html and then uploads it on a host.

```
image: node:4.2.2

variables:
  HOST: "myhost"
  USERNAME: "myusername"
  PASSWORD: "mypassword"

pages:
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - npm install -g markdown-styles -y 
  - generate-md  --input ./ --output ./output --layout mixu-bootstrap-2col
  - cd output
  - pwd
  - ls
  - apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y -qq lftp
  - lftp -c  "set ftp:ssl-allow no; open -u $USERNAME,$PASSWORD $HOST; mirror -Rnev ./ ./www  -e --delete-first --parallel=10 --exclude-glob .git* --exclude .sh --exclude .gitlab-ci.yml --exclude /node_modules/*" 
  only:
   - master
```